# Using If not function(): to control flow in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, methods, boolean, control-flow

I have an object class with an update method: this method simply makes a few checks and updates the object's properties, <s>nothing is returned</s> a Bool is returned to determine whether it should be deleted.

Some of these checks outcomes preclude others execution:
EDIT, Old Code Block:

```
def updateObject(self):
    self.checkOne()

    if not self.checkTwo():
        self.checkThree():

def checkTwo(self):
    if self.x == condition:
        self.y = different value
        return True
    return False
```

New Code Block:

```
class MyObject():
    def __init__(self, firstValueHash: int):
        self.identifier # str (unused in this example)
        self.isMarked # bool
    
        # maxObserved is always greater than maxTrackedTicks
        self.maxObservedTicks # int
        self.maxTrackedTicks # int
        self.ticksSinceUpdate # int
        self.ticksSinceMarked # int
        self.trackData = [None]*self.maxObservedTicks-1 # list of ints
        self.trackData.append(firstValueHash)


    # called externally once every 5 mins, returns True if object needs deleting, otherwise returns false
    def performUpdate(self):
        self.ticksSinceUpdate += 1


        self.trackData = self.trackData[1:(self.maxObservedTicks-1)]
        self.trackData.append(None) # some other function updates these None values
        
        if self.ticksSinceUpdate > self.maxObservedTicks:
            return True

        if not self.__updateIfMarked():
            self.__updateIfExpired():
        
        return False

    def __updateIfMarked(self):
        if self.isMarked == True:
            self.ticksSinceMarked += 1
            
            if self.ticksSinceMarked < maxObservedTicks
                return True

            self.isMarked = False
            self.ticksSinceMarked = 0

        return False
        
    def __updateIfExpired(self):
        if self.ticksSinceUpdate >= maxTrackedTicks:
            self.isMarked = None

    # Other functions will update of isMarked outside of the 5 min update, by labelling it as True or False
```

As you can see, the outcome of <s>checkTwo</s> updateIfMarked() determines whether <s>checkThree</s> __updateIfExpired() occurs by returning a Bool.

This felt really uncomfortable to write, but it's the most clear and concise way I can think of to get the behavior I want.

Is this bad practice? I feel like it breaks the "one tool; one job" rule. I also think that it might make the behavior unclear due to excessive logical inversions...

Comment: *"I feel like it breaks the "one tool; one job" rule"* Why so? `checkTwo` has one job (if we ignore the fact that it also changes the value of `y` as a side effect), to decide if a certain condition is true or false. It just happens to be that the execution of `checkThree` is dependent on that condition. Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: There is no `checkOne` or `checkThree` function in your example. Your code is not valid python. Can you include a [MRE]? Whether this is good practice depends on your use case. This looks like the function calls could be `if` `else` statements

Comment: Not a bad practice at all! The code is clear, partitioned and does what it intends. What scruples can there be?

Comment: Whether or not this is bad is impossible to say, since you've chose to remove the actual logic and are just showing meaningless checks. It's possible that you're overcomplicating things in your own code, or that there'd be a more concise and readable way to write it, but it's impossible to say without seeing it in context.

Comment: Is there any reason why ``__updateIfMarked`` and ``__updateIfExpired`` aren't just *one* function? The latter is so small it could be trivially inlined into the former.

Comment: Why does ``__updateIfExpired`` assign ``self.isMarked = None``? This doesn't seem to make sense wrt the rest of the code, which seems to expect only booleans.

Comment: I tried writing an answer, but this code is such a tangled mess that hardly does anything that I gave up. All it really does is create some sort of sliding buffer of some size and keep track of how often it is "updated" until the entire buffer has passed, at which point it is apparently "deleted". And in the meantime, it can be marked and keeps track of how often it is updated while marked as well. Unless you can explain what problem you're solving here, trying to improve this code is pointless - it seems like 90% of it is superfluous.

Comment: @Grismar You've described the intended behavior perfectly, I didn't really want to expand upon the broader purpose because it introduces more complexity than I can concisely describe in a post.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm using None as a 3rd state, where True and False objects are picked up by a state reporting function, but None are skipped over until they are either deleted or gain sufficient data to become True or False again.

Comment: Note that since you seem to be looking for general improvements on working code, this appears to more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ah, that may indeed be more appropriate.  I believe I've answered my own question, but I'll look into CodeReview, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out why writing this felt wrong:

If we look closely at `if not self.__updateIfMarked()` statement's overall behavior, it essentially says "execute `__updateIfExpired()` whenever the bool `self.isMarked` is False, but only after executing `__updateIfTicked`.

Crucially, `self.isMarked` is *determined* by the outcome of `__updateIfTicked`, so there must always be two checks of whether `isTicked` is True or False.  Returning True or False to the if operator from `__updateIfTicked` is synonymous with:

```
    def performUpdate(self):
        self.ticksSinceUpdate += 1


        self.trackData = self.trackData[1:(self.maxObservedTicks-1)]
        self.trackData.append(None) # some other function updates these None values
        
        if self.ticksSinceUpdate > self.maxObservedTicks:
            return True

        self.__updateIfMarked():
        self.__updateIfExpired():
        
        return False

    def __updateIfMarked(self):
        if self.isMarked == True:
            self.ticksSinceMarked += 1
            
            if self.ticksSinceMarked >= maxObservedTicks
                self.isMarked = False
                self.ticksSinceMarked = 0
        
    def __updateIfExpired(self):
        if self.ticksSinceUpdate >= maxTrackedTicks and self.isMarked = False:
            self.isMarked = None
```

The order of operation is crucial to getting the intended behavior: a sliding buffer which preserved 'Marked' entities beyond the Tracking window.

Whether you should use None as a third state is maybe questionable.  Perhaps an enum would be more appropriate?